# EF6/SQL Server Compact, code-based configuration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-4.0, sql-server-ce

I'm trying to move my EF6 configuration from `myexe.exe.config` to code as a workaround for the `empty DbProviderFactories node in machine.config`-issue (described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24273922/600559). I don't want to change the `machine.config` file.

I have read the [Code-Based Configuration (EF6 onwards)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj680699.aspx).

I have tried implementations like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23130602/600559, however I cannot get it to work. Does anyone have a working EF6/SQL CE/code-based configuration solution?

Here's my my changes (from a working .config solution to a code based solution):
New class added:

```
public class DatabaseConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public DatabaseConfiguration()
    {
        SetExecutionStrategy("System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0", () => new DefaultExecutionStrategy());
        SetProviderFactory("System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0", new SqlCeProviderFactory());
        SetProviderServices("System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0", SqlCeProviderServices.Instance);
    }
}
```

Then the `system.data` and `entityFramework` node in the `.config`-file is removed.

Now this works, however the `machine.config` files is read: If a have the `<DbProviderFactories/>` in `machine.config` I get this exception:

[image: Exception]

So the real problem is not that the code based configuration does not work, the problem is that the `machine.config` configuration is still being read and causes issues. Anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: Please expand: does not Work, or nobody can help you. Is the configuration code not called, or do you get errors?

Comment: @ErikEJ i have added more informations - btw I'm a big fan of your work

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution. Implementing a `IDbProviderFactoryResolver` that does not read from the `machine.config` file:

```
  public class CodeBasedDatabaseConfiguration : DbConfiguration
  {
    public CodeBasedDatabaseConfiguration()
    {
      SetExecutionStrategy("System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0", () => new DefaultExecutionStrategy());
      SetProviderFactory("System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0", new SqlCeProviderFactory());
      SetProviderServices("System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0", SqlCeProviderServices.Instance);
      SetProviderFactoryResolver(new CodeBasedDbProviderFactoryResolver());
    }
  }

  internal class CodeBasedDbProviderFactoryResolver : IDbProviderFactoryResolver
  {
    private readonly DbProviderFactory sqlServerCeDbProviderFactory = new SqlCeProviderFactory();

    public DbProviderFactory ResolveProviderFactory(DbConnection connection)
    {
      var connectionType = connection.GetType();
      var assembly = connectionType.Assembly;
      if (assembly.FullName.Contains("System.Data.SqlServerCe"))
      {
        return sqlServerCeDbProviderFactory;
      }
      if (assembly.FullName.Contains("EntityFramework"))
      {
        return EntityProviderFactory.Instance;
      }
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: That is not a robust solution. Use my EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact.PrivateDeployment NuGet package, which would save you some code to maintain, and be robust - with you current solution you will run into runtime errors if a different version of the 4.0 runtime is installed in GAC on the target PC, as the version of the ADO.NET provider (System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll) will attempt to load unmanaged dll files of the wrong version.

Comment: @ErikEJ - Thanks for your comments. I'm reading your blog post http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2013/11/entity-framework-6-sql-server-compact-4_25.html and I'm getting scared. I have seen private deployment of SqlCE as very simple - never thought about GAC conflicts. I will take a look at EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact.PrivateDeployment.

Comment: Thanks, Morten. The important post is actually http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2014/10/entity-framework-6-and-sql-server.html

Comment: @ErikEJ - my bad - it was the http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2014/10/entity-framework-6-and-sql-server.html post i meant